# How to search issue by filter in Redmine

Tags: objective-c, redmine

I want to search issue by filter (status, Tracker, Priority, ...) in Redmine. I do not know how to start this in objective-c.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Any REST library for Objective-C](http://restkit.org/) and [Redmine REST API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues)
Take a look on this [iOS sample application](https://github.com/maltzsama/RedmineBugTracker-iOS) which is sending Issues to redmine. You can adopt it to retrieve issues using REST API guide from redmine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if such a feature is implemented in redmine to filter your search. mentioned [here](http://www.redmine.org/issues/8205)  and [here](http://www.redmine.org/issues/992) and [here.](http://www.redmine.org/issues/2829) But one can contribute to an open source project and implement new feature. For that have look at the bottom of [this page](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Guide) and contact Redmine mailing list. You will get better support there.